# phpDocumentor2 - Update Selective Classes

Tags: php, phpdocumentor2

I am new to phpDocumentor2. I was wondering if its possible to just update specific file without updating the whole directory. Please refer to example directory structure below.

```
Classes (Directory)
  Controller (Directory)
  - Class_A.php
  - Class_A.php
  - Class_A.php
  Model (Directory)
  - Model_1.php
  - Model_2.php
  - Model_3.php
```

Is there an option to only update Classes/Controller/Class_B.php or do I have to update everything under Classes/? If possible, is there also any option to add a new class file to an existing documentation?

Comment: There is no update command, but you can benefit from the incremental parsing mechanism mentioned here [Documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/configuration.html#basic-configuration)

Comment: Also PHPDoc is caching the analyzed scripts. So it's very time efficient even on large projects. If you only want to update certain regions of your code base for other reasons you might want to take a look at the [directory option](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/commands/project_run.html#parameters) (although that might remove the rest of your documentation)